# How to change icon shape in Android 12 Splash screen?

Tags: android, android-12

- I want splash screen icon in Rectangle shape instead of rounded shape in android 12

Answer (score 3):

Make your logo's canvas around 35% bigger, with the square logo in the middle, keeping the logo the same size. Then Android 12 will round a 1/3rd of the image, but your logo will be untouched.

Comment: putting a square peg in a round hole.  I hate the Google forces us to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can. If you look at point 3 here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/splash-screen#elements
It describes the image "As with adaptive icons, ⅓ of the foreground is masked"

The shape of the icon shown is just whatever shape is being used by the system for adaptive icons.

The splash screen changes in android 12 are specifically to reduce the amount of customisation you can do on splash screens, to keep the UX more consistent between apps. The customisation options that *do* exist are detailed on that page too.

Comment: To add to this, the mask used is the same that the launcher uses and is defined by the manufacturer, who can make it customizable like Google did in previous version of Android.