# Change Splash screen icon shape Android 12

Tags: svg, icons, splash-screen, android-12

I would like to use a decent size rectangle shape icon in android 12 splash screen, even though the icon I use is rectangle shape it is always displayed in a circle shape.  I saw one question / answer here,
[How to change icon shape in Android 12 Splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847161/how-to-change-icon-shape-in-android-12-splash-screen)
If I follow the answer from here, the icon is rectangle but it is small?

Like, this netflix is good size one (which is from android 12 phone), and I would like to make a similar one.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I read the documentation carefully, and it cannot use wider space! It stated

> For example, if the full size of an image is 300×300 dp, the icon needs to fit within a circle with a diameter of 200 dp. Everything outside the circle will be invisible (masked).

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen#splash_screen_dimensions
[image]
I was using an icon with background originally, so I was able to use only 160dp, however, once change the icon to be without background, I can use 192dp(or 200dp?) as the documentation, which is enough space for us.

I had to modify my image size by adding  in our svg file to fit in the circle.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="1920dp"
android:height="492dp"
android:viewportWidth="1920"
android:viewportHeight="492">
<group
    android:pivotX="960"
    android:pivotY="246"
    android:scaleX="0.65"
    android:scaleY="0.17">
<path .../>
<path .../>
</group>
</vector>
```

Comment: This new API really sucks, my case is I that don't want to place the icon in the center